# Does blender have this tool : merge every vertices at certain distance point

Tags: vertices

Hi i can do this with single command in Modo, but hard to find the sama function in Blender. Can anyone help ?
pls see the attachment , i have 8 vertices and i want to merge so the adjacent vertex will blend together , to say to become 4 vertices. The mege vertex in blender will merge them all together become 1 single vertex. Or i have to do it for every 2 vertices and repeat the same process. Look, this is just the simple example. We may easily fix this using other method like dissolving edges etc. So here's the real case : I have a head model which is very high detail polygon. There's imperfections of previous edit , so there's some vertices which is look like single vertex but if i zoom it really close , i found 2vertices (also can be 3 or more) that are really close to each other . The problem is it happen sporadically randomly spread acrross the model. I can't inspect one by one as it's hundreds of poly.

So in modo i have a very handy tool that can fix this in single click. WHere it scan the overall model and find each the adjacent 2 or more vertices (at the treshold we can set ) and blend them. And repeat the process automatically until all vertices is fixed.

In Blender , i can't find that tool. So i have to find it myself and merge them. Can someone tell me where is this tool ?[image]

Comment: It's called remove doubles and accessible through the Specials Menu: **w** > remove doubles. You can adjust the merge distance after applying the operation in the tools panel.

Comment: @ceg I would have expected this to be a duplicate, every 10th question includes a *remove doubles* or *recalculate normals*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called remove doubles and accessible through the Specials Menu: <kbd>W</kbd> > *remove doubles*. You can adjust the merge distance after applying the operation in the tools panel.

1. Select the geometry in question (or all geometry with <kbd>A</kbd>).
2. Remove double through the <kbd>W</kbd> specials menu.
3. Adjust the *merge distance* if needed.

[image]

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles):

> Remove Doubles is a useful tool to simplify a mesh by merging the selected vertices that are closer than a specified distance to each other. An alternative way to simplify a mesh is to use the Decimate Modifier.

*Using the decimate modifier will be not pay exceptional attention to the distance though and is in this case not useful.*

Answer (score 1):

With Blender 2.8 (non-beta) out, now there's a Merge Vertex by Distance tool within the merge tool itself.
The quick way of using it is to group-select all the vertices that needs to be verified, press ALT + M and select "By Distance". Then entering the right distance will merge all exceeding vertex within those selected.

Comment: That's not a 'tool'. That can be called an operation or a function or an operator, but it's best not to call this a tool, because tools are different things in Blender now and this might confuse people new to Blender.